# How do I get the raw JSON output from an http post request in Angular?

Tags: angular, authentication, crud

In the below, I'm calling a backend api to validate a user login and returns errors or success in simple JSON output

```js
export class AuthService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getUserDetails(email, password): Observable<any> {
        // post to API server - return user info if valid

        return this.http.post('http://localhost/api/myapp/task_login.php', {
            email,
            password
        })
        .pipe(
            map((response:Response)=>response.json())
        );
    }
}
```

I followed a ton of different guides online and eventually ended up with this to try and get it to simply reply with whatever the php file responded with. I just want the raw output so I can act on it appropriately. I'm calling this from a component file like so:

```js
        var response:any = this.Auth.getUserDetails(email, password);
        console.log(response);
        if (response.success)
            $location.path('/home');
```

When I look at the console, I get some kind of Observable object that doesn't seem to actually contain the data I need (that I can find, that's a deep object). How do I properly return whatever the request replied with?

Comment: this.Auth.getUserDetails(email, password).subscribe ...   https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: Your method `getUserDetails` returns an Observable. You need to subscribe to the observable to get the response object. 
`this.Auth.getUserDetails(email, password).subscribe(res => console.log(res))`; for example.

Comment: Riscie: Using subscribe as you showed results in an error that response.json isn't a function. Something seems wrong on the observable side (edit: I took out the pipe entirely and it works now! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `getUserDetails` returns an Observable. You need to subscribe to the Observable to get the response object.

```
this.Auth.getUserDetails(email, password)
    .subscribe(res => {
         // do something with your object
         console.log(res);
    }
);
```

for example.

You can read about Observables in the angular documentation: https://angular.io/guide/observables or on the Library (RxJS) homepage: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable

**Edit**
Also, you don't need the pipe in your service:

```
getUserDetails(email, password): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost/api/myapp/task_login.php', 
    {
        email,
        password
    });
}
```

Comment: That did it, thank you! I've been following so many different guides and none of them seem to agree on exactly how this is done, but it looks like I was close. I made the changes you suggested and I'm now seeing the direct output of my php file in the console so communication is happening!

Comment: glad I was of help.the various tutorials can be daunting in the beginning, I certainly experienced this myself.

Answer (score 0):

I think code should modify.

```
export class AuthService {
   constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

   getUserDetails(email, password): Observable<any> {
    // post to API server - return user info if valid

      return this.http.post('http://localhost/api/myapp/task_login.php', {
          'email':email,
          'password':password
     })
    .pipe(
        map((response:Response)=>response.json())
    );
}
```

Also, you can use "Subscribe" for the response.

```
this.Auth.getUserDetails(email, password).subscribe((data)=>{
   console.log(data);
```

}, (err)=>console.log(err));